# Get key from first array on Search Array in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some question about searching a value in multidimensional array.
This is my code

```
$groep = array(
                1 => array("111","222"),
                2 => array("333","444")
                );
$groepje = 0;
foreach($groep as $row => $value){
    if(array_search($serial,$value)){
        $groepje = $row;
    }
}
```

Now i want to set $groepje to the 'head'key of the array, so if $serial = 111 it have to give back 1, if $serial = 444 it have to give back 2.

What i do get is the wrong number, so 0 if its 111 or 333.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `$serial` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use `in_array` to search for the specified serial.
- I renamed some of your variables to make it clearer.
- Used `break` to break out of the loop once we know we've found what we're looking for.
- assuming you define `$serial` above your `foreach`

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca34f236ca2d19af8c098120de1707f14bed285a

```
<?php

$groep = array(
    1 => array("111","222"),
    2 => array("333","444")
);

$groepje = 0;
$serial= '333';

foreach($groep as $key => $data) {
    
    if (in_array($serial, $data)) {
        $groepje = $key;
        break;
    }
}

// 2
echo $groepje;
```